# Stupid Android Layout Tricks

Tags: android, android-layout

Android Layouts have changed a bit since I've been away from the topic and I never had to get this deep into it before, so forgive what I hope is a relatively simple question.

Say you are developing a card game with a human player and 3 computer or remote opponents (not quite accurate, but close enough for my purposes). My plan is that there will be four children Layouts representing each of the player's "hands". The ones on the left and right will display their images in top down order. The ones on the top and bottom will display their images in left-to right order.

It's reasonable to assume Left and Right Layouts will have identical (gravity, right?) behavior (if different start and end pixels). Same goes for Top and Bottom. If it matters, usage will be restricted to Landscape mode.

What is the correct method of getting said childLayouts into their correct locations? What's the correct top level layout(s) to use for this? What should the player's children layouts be? (I have assumed GridLayouts, but it seemsa host of others might work too -- they will do nothing but hold a number of dynamically generated ImageViews)

Once I've got layouts in the right location, I'm good...I think.

Tx in advance

Comment: My suggestion is that, if you're developing a game, you use a game engine to create it. I've created a game by using native Android layouts, but boy, was it hacky! It's just that the UI functionality is adapted to apps, not games...

Comment: I've actually gone back and forth on the subject. I created a primitive version of what I did in python using pygame and wasn't happy with the results.

All I really need are 4 boxes I can refer to programatically. The Android Layouts seem perfect for this if I could get them to the right location.

Comment: I will try to answer your question soon...

Comment: Can you make a sketch on what you're trying to achieve? Like, in Paint or something like that?

Comment: Give me a little bit to retool the pygame version and I;ll post a ss

Comment: I will have to agree with @AleksandarStefanović on this one. I too have played with making a native game and it can get to be mighty funny looking in regards to the code. A lot of work is put into the engines, I would recommend at least looking at them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer apparently is to use the layout_width and layout_height params for a gridLayout specifying where they need to be inside of a relativeLayout (in this case I know I am using a 1200 x 600 device, but I'm sure there is a better way to go about this.

```
<GridLayout
        android:layout_width="500px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/NORTH">
</GridLayout>

<GridLayout
        android:layout_width="500px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/SOUTH">
</GridLayout>

<GridLayout
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="500px"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/WEST">
</GridLayout>

<GridLayout
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="500px"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/EAST">
```